# How can I download DNRGPS?

Tags: google-chrome, download, links, file-download, gps

When I clicked the link on https://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html to download the program, it popped up with a dialog box to open with program or close. The only programs it gave me options for were browsers, so I thought it was asking me what browser to use to download it. I clicked google chrome since that's my go-to. Unfortunately, now all it does is open in a new tab with the file (ftp://ftp.dnr.state.mn.us/pub/gisftp/DNRGPS/dnrgps.zip) in the URL bar and gives me a blank, "Untitled" page. Is there any way around this?

I tried deleting my cache and browsing history to se if it lets me select something else, but that didn't work. I also tried using a different browser, but that didn't work either. I need this program for my GIS class, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You told your computer to use Chrome to open FTP sites. Open the site in a different browser, right-click on the very clear download links there on the page and select Save Target As... to download the file and avoid Chrome.

Comment: When I right-click, the save as option is grayed out so I can't select that

Comment: What browser did you do that in?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome does not support the ftp protocol which you want to use to download the .zip file containing your programme. I just checked, and edge does not support it either. I do not have other browsers than FireFox installed to test it on, but I know that FireFox definitely can open ftp links. Just either enter it in your address bar and press enter or when you have it on some website, rightclick and choose *Save Target As...* just as @music2myear suggested. The alternative would be to enter the first part of the URL *ftp://ftp.dnr.state.mn.us/pub/gisftp/DNRGPS/* directly inside the path field of your Windows Explorer and then search for the dnrgps.zip file in the now open file tree. Although there are many many files in there so it could be quite some searching for it.

Comment: In Firefox 88.0 - "FTP support has been disabled, and its full removal is planned for an upcoming release. Addressing this security risk reduces the likelihood of an attack while also removing support for a non-encrypted protocol."

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh, I didn't know that. But it makes sense, as ftp is a very bad protocol anyways. Still, if this is the only way you can download this file, then you have to use it. And for now, Firefox works. This may change with any update, but then you have to look into new ways of getting your hands on files that are provided only via ftp...